# Vertical line for the the right margin in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Does anyone know if Notepad++ can display a vertical line on the right margin to indicated that the text will or will not fit on a printed page?  I have looked but I cannot find it.  Word wrap does work, but it wraps by my screen width, not by the width of a printed page.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

As you said you do not actually want to print it, you may use the **Vertical Edge Settings**.

> Setting > Preferences > Editing > **Vertical Edge Settings** > Input column position(s) seperated with space, for example `80 100`

Vertical lines would then be shown at the positions specified (e.g. column 80 & column 100).

You can tick *Background mode* if you prefer highlighted text instead of a line.

(Tested in: Notepad++ v7.8.9)

In version 8.1.3, the above is under:

> Settings > Preference > Margins/Border/Edge > **Vertical Edge Settings**

Comment: It's still there in v**6.8.8** (December, 2015).

Comment: Only issue I have with the vertical edge is that Word Wrap doesn't respect it. It would be wonderful to be able to check a box in the editing preferences to get this behavior.

Comment: @KeithS you are correct. notepad++ doesn't support this feature yet. https://superuser.com/questions/365225/how-do-i-wrap-lines-in-notepad-after-n-symbols

Comment: In newer *Notepad++* (7.8.6) the option is named Vertical Edge Settings, and allows to highlight several columns at once.

Comment: Yes, and for completeness, it moved from Editing to 
Settings > Preferences > Margins/Border/Edge.

Answer (score 38):

BTW You can also customize the color of that vertical bar here:

[image: vertical edge color customizing in Notepad++]

Answer (score 18):

In case you are looking for this option in Notepad++ at ~v7.8, the setting is located near the center of the "Vertical Edge Settings" window under `Settings > Preferences > Editing`:

You can type in one or more numbers (separated by white space) to show one or multiple vertical lines.

In the example below, I have a "warning" line at line 70, and a hard limit at 80. Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: this section has now moved to `Settings > Preferences > Margins/Border/Edge` (I am using v8.1.9.2)

Answer (score 2):

this section has now moved to `Settings > Preferences > Margins/Border/Edge` (I am using v8.1.9.2)

Answer (score 1):

To get a vertical line, go to `Settings > Preferences > Margins/Border/Edge` and type the line width in `Vertical Edge Settings` as a number:

[image: Vertical Edge Settings screenshot]

`Background mode` modifies the color of the text instead of adding a line:

[image: Background mode screenshot]

You can have multiple lines by typing multiple numbers, which makes Background mode impossible though:

[image: multiple edges screenshot]

To change the color of the line, go to `Settings > Style Configurator`. In `Language: Global`, `Style: Edge colour`'s `Foreground colour` is what controls this.

[image: style configuration screenshot]

This also affects the Background mode:

[image: screenshot of effect of style configuration on the background mode (text on the right of the invisible line has a red background)]

(This is as of Notepad++ v8.5.4 Jun 17 2023)

Answer (score 0):

> I think modern Printers are able to
>   auto adjust words so that can fit in
>   the sheet. So don't worry about
>   margins.

I suggest you use to Microsoft Word for typing documents that you want to print.

**EDIT:** I couldn't find anything that could provide a vertical margin in Notepad++. But as Workaround for text readability, once the text is written **select all the text** then press 
**Ctrl + I** (shortcut for Split Lines). One Disadvantage is that you have to keep your window size steady i.e don't resize it.

Comment: I actually do not want to print it, I just want the code to look nice and appear in a readable fashion.  Having that line lets me know when to press 'ENTER'.

Comment: Split LINES! CTRL+i BRILLIANT. NOTE: First, turn on word-wrap. This doesn't change your document, only the way it 'wraps' on the screen. Next, resize your window-width, select your text, then run this command. It will add new-lines to each line that goes beyond the window width.