# Code length limiter in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vertical line for the the right margin in Notepad++](https://superuser.com/questions/185736/vertical-line-for-the-the-right-margin-in-notepad)

Hi I am using Notepad++. In some IDE's like Netbeans, we can see a vertical line in the code editor to emphasis the recommended number of characters per line. Is there a plugin for notepad++ which helps with the same?

[image]

In the above image, you can see a thin vertical line in the editor.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Follow these steps

- Go to Settings -> Preferences... -> Editing -> Show vertical edge.
- Set the "Number of Columns" value. This will show you a vertical line on screen.
- Select the text whose width you want to set.
- Then go to TextFX Edit >> ReWrap text to (Clipboard or 72) width

This will set width to 72 by default.

If you want set specific width then write that width or number (say 80) anywhere and copy it and remove it.

Then again go to TextFX Edit >> ReWrap text to (Clipboard or 72) width

This time it will set width of selected text to 80.

Comment: I will add something, it is possible to re-wrap text with NotePad++ only by using "Word Wrap" under "View" menu