# How do I start another line after certain column in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I want to start a new line after my cursor position reaches at 80th coulmn. It's was pretty simple with proper settings on vim, but I can't see similar setting on Notepad++.

What I already tried are:

- Settings > Preferences > Editing > Vertical Edge Settings

The problem with this is, it only shows the line number, not starts a new line from there.

- View > Word Wrap

It wraps, but not start a new line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I wrap lines in Notepad++ after N symbols?](http://superuser.com/questions/365225/how-do-i-wrap-lines-in-notepad-after-n-symbols)

Comment: @DavidPostill You are just searching and forcefully marking as duplicated. If you have carefully read my question, you'll note that I have already read that question and my second **tried** point is already taken from that question itself. Please don't do this! Don't make wrong use of admin privileges.

Comment: You must have missed reading "**No, it is not possible is current versions of Notepad++. There is a feature request for it, but it has not been implemented yet.**"

Comment: In addition, I only marked it as a possible duplicate. It takes 4 more votes or agreement from you to close as a duplicate.

Comment: You didn't mention in your question you have read that link. From [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask): "Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. **Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs**. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!"