# Notepad++ 80 Character Line Marker?

Tags: notepad++

Is there a way I can get a vertical marker line to appear at the 80th character column in notepad++?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Yes.

Settings > Preferences > Editing > Vertical Edge Settings

([This does not reflect the latest UI, for that, please see this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1562046/55641))

[image: options page]

[image: result]

Tested on N++ 5.9

Comment: That works, thanks! But strangely, it seems to be off by two columns for me when you compare it to the column counter in the status bar.

Comment: @speedplane: yeah I just noticed that! then number-of-columns: 78 haha?

Comment: At some point before v6.5.2, the column number location has been fixed so is no longer off by two.

Comment: Here it marks way before the 80 mark.

Comment: Worth noting: the UI has changed. https://superuser.com/questions/185736/vertical-line-for-the-the-right-margin-in-notepad